# Reading content from a URL failing

Tags: android, buffer, inputstream

I am trying to read a JSON from a web page and store it as a string, however when debugging it keeps failing in the try statement at line:

BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));

```
public String networkRequest() throws IOException {

    URL url = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/me");

    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    try
    {
        InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        int cp;
        while ((cp = bufferedReader.read()) != -1)
        {
            stringBuilder.append((char) cp);
        }

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return "nothing";
    }
}
```

In which because of the fail reaches the catch and returns "nothing", does anyone understand what I am doing wrong?

BTW: My network is perfectly fine!

Comment: Log the exception inside of your catch block. By doing `Log.d("TAG", ex + "");` and then in your Logcat, see what the exception is.

Comment: are you executing this method from UI thread? Please post your exception here for further help.

Comment: @BidhanA So I get this exception, android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: @user950933 I get a NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: Great. It means you are executing this method from UI thread which is not recommended and android strict mode will not allow this. Hence there is an exception. Please execute the method from a background thread.

Comment: Did you add internet permission to your AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: @strings95 Yup I did!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android HttpClient : NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736530/android-httpclient-networkonmainthreadexception)

Answer (score 0):

Great. It means you are executing this method from UI thread which is not recommended and android strict mode will not allow this. Hence there is an exception. Please execute the method from a background thread.

Comment: When you say 'background thread' can I ask what do you mean? As this method is in a class which is called from a method in my presenter (following MVP design pattern)

Comment: You should create a new Java thread or runnable object and execute this method.

Comment: Can you lead me to the correct tutorials? I don't understand what you are saying

Comment: developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html