# How to use work manager with GoogleApiClient and retrofit?

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk, android-workmanager

So I'm using Worker Manger to open my app on the background, collect data from google fit and send it to server.

- I tried calling api inside my worker and it works well.
- then I tried to connect to google fit and collect data and it worked well as well.

but when I tried to combine the 2 points together it didn't work . 
it always throws `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` with null message

can anyone give me a reason why this is happening?

here is my code

```
class TrackWorker(context: Context, params: WorkerParameters) : Worker(context, params), GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

@Inject
lateinit var useCase: TrackUseCase
val TAG: String = TrackWorker::class.java.simpleName
private var client: GoogleApiClient? = null
private var totalSteps: Int = 0
private var totalDistance: Float = 0f


override fun onConnectionFailed(p0: ConnectionResult) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Failed")
}

override fun onConnected(p0: Bundle?) {
    val ESTIMATED_STEP_DELTAS = DataSource.Builder()
            .setAppPackageName("com.google.android.gms")
            .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
            .setType(DataSource.TYPE_DERIVED)
            .setStreamName("estimated_steps")
            .build()
    val readRequest = DataReadRequest.Builder()
            .aggregate(ESTIMATED_STEP_DELTAS, DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
            .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA, DataType.AGGREGATE_DISTANCE_DELTA)
            .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED, DataType.AGGREGATE_CALORIES_EXPENDED)
            .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT, DataType.AGGREGATE_ACTIVITY_SUMMARY)
            .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
            .setTimeRange(CalendarUtil.getFirstDayOfWeek(), CalendarUtil.getNow(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build()


    val result = Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(client, readRequest)
    val totalResult = result.setResultCallback { it ->

        if (it.status.isSuccess) {
            val buckets = it.buckets
            for (bucket in buckets) {
                val dataSets = bucket.dataSets

                for (dataSet in dataSets) {
                    if (dataSet.dataType.name == "com.google.step_count.delta") {
                        for (dp in dataSet.dataPoints) {
                            for (field in dp.dataType.fields) {
                                val steps = dp.getValue(field).asInt()
                                totalSteps += steps
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                for (dataSet in dataSets) {
                    if (dataSet.dataType.name == "com.google.distance.delta") {
                        for (dp in dataSet.dataPoints) {
                            for (field in dp.dataType.fields) {
                                val distance = dp.getValue(field).asFloat()
                                totalDistance += distance
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "There was a problem getting the step count")
        }

        if (totalSteps != 0 && totalDistance != 0f) {
            val jsonArray = JsonArray()
            val trackBodyJSON = JsonObject()


            trackBodyJSON.addProperty("trackDate", CalendarUtil.getCurrentDate())
            trackBodyJSON.addProperty("walksteps", totalSteps)
            trackBodyJSON.addProperty("walkkm", totalDistance)
            jsonArray.add(trackBodyJSON)


            useCase.execute(TrackUseCase.Request(jsonArray))
                    .subscribe({
                        Log.d(TAG, "it's here $it")
                    }, {
                        Log.d(TAG, "errorrrr ${it}")
                        when (it) {
                            is ApiException ->
                                Log.d(TAG, "API ERROR ? ${it.apiErrorResponse.message}")
                            is TimeoutConnectionException -> {
                                Log.d(TAG, "API ERROR ? Timeout")
                            }
                            else -> {
                                Log.d(TAG, "error ${it.localizedMessage}")
                            }
                        }
                    })


        }
    }


}

override fun onConnectionSuspended(p0: Int) {
    Log.d(TAG, "SUSSPENDED")
}


override fun doWork(): Result {
    (applicationContext as WalkAndTalkApp).component().inject(this)

    if (client == null) {
        client = GoogleApiClient.Builder(applicationContext)
                .addApi(Fitness.RECORDING_API)
                .addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
                .addScope(Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_LOCATION_READ))
                .addScope(Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE))
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build()

        if (!client!!.isConnected)
            client!!.connect()
    }


    return Result.SUCCESS
}

}
```

I tried using chaining worker managers, but the second worker gets executed before the first one connecting to the google fit sdk and getting data

below is the code

```
 private var totalSteps: Int = 0
private var totalDistance: Float = 0f
val TAG: String = "DAILYTRAKWORKER"

class ConnectWorker(context: Context, params: WorkerParameters) : Worker(context, params), GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private var client: GoogleApiClient? = null



    override fun onConnectionFailed(p0: ConnectionResult) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Failed")
    }

    override fun onConnected(p0: Bundle?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "CONNNNECTED")

        val ESTIMATED_STEP_DELTAS = DataSource.Builder()
                .setAppPackageName("com.google.android.gms")
                .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                .setType(DataSource.TYPE_DERIVED)
                .setStreamName("estimated_steps")
                .build()
        val readRequest = DataReadRequest.Builder()
                .aggregate(ESTIMATED_STEP_DELTAS, DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA, DataType.AGGREGATE_DISTANCE_DELTA)
                .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED, DataType.AGGREGATE_CALORIES_EXPENDED)
                .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT, DataType.AGGREGATE_ACTIVITY_SUMMARY)
                .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                .setTimeRange(CalendarUtil.getFirstDayOfWeek(), CalendarUtil.getNow(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .build()


        val result = Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(client, readRequest)
        result.setResultCallback { it ->

            if (it.status.isSuccess) {
                val buckets = it.buckets
                for (bucket in buckets) {
                    val dataSets = bucket.dataSets
                    for (dataSet in dataSets) {
                        if (dataSet.dataType.name == "com.google.step_count.delta") {
                            for (dp in dataSet.dataPoints) {
                                for (field in dp.dataType.fields) {
                                    val steps = dp.getValue(field).asInt()
                                    totalSteps += steps
                                    Log.d(TAG, "steps: $steps")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    for (dataSet in dataSets) {
                        if (dataSet.dataType.name == "com.google.distance.delta") {
                            for (dp in dataSet.dataPoints) {
                                for (field in dp.dataType.fields) {
                                    val distance = dp.getValue(field).asFloat()
                                    Log.d(TAG, "distance: " + distance / 1000)
                                    totalDistance += distance
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "There was a problem getting the step count")
            }

        }


    }

    override fun onConnectionSuspended(p0: Int) {
        Log.d(TAG, "SUSSPENDED")
    }

    override fun doWork(): Result {

        if (client == null) {
            client = GoogleApiClient.Builder(applicationContext)
                    .addApi(Fitness.RECORDING_API)
                    .addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
                    .addScope(Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_LOCATION_READ))
                    .addScope(Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE))
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build()

            if (!client!!.isConnected)
                client!!.connect()
        }
        return Result.SUCCESS
    }


}

class TrackWorker(context: Context, params: WorkerParameters) : Worker(context, params) {


    @Inject
    lateinit var useCase: TrackUseCase


    override fun doWork(): Result {
        (applicationContext as WalkAndTalkApp).component().inject(this)
        Log.i(TAG, "trackworker:$totalSteps ")

        if (totalSteps != 0 && totalDistance != 0f) {
            val jsonArray = JsonArray()
            val trackBodyJSON = JsonObject()
            Log.i(TAG, "Total steps:$totalSteps ")
            Log.i(TAG, "Total Distance:$totalDistance ")
            Log.d(TAG, "CURRENT DATE ${CalendarUtil.getCurrentDate()}")

            trackBodyJSON.addProperty("trackDate", CalendarUtil.getCurrentDate())
            trackBodyJSON.addProperty("walksteps", totalSteps)
            trackBodyJSON.addProperty("walkkm", totalDistance)
            jsonArray.add(trackBodyJSON)


            Log.d(TAG, "LIST --->   $jsonArray")

            useCase.execute(TrackUseCase.Request(jsonArray))
                    .subscribe({
                        Log.d(TAG, "it's here $it")
                    }, {
                        Log.d(TAG, "errorrrr ${it}")
                        when (it) {
                            is ApiException ->
                                Log.d(TAG, "API ERROR ?       ${it.apiErrorResponse.message}")
                            is TimeoutConnectionException -> {
                                Log.d(TAG, "API ERROR ? Timeout")
                            }

                            else -> {
                                Log.d(TAG, "error ${it.localizedMessage}")
                            }
                        }
                    })
        }

        return Result.SUCCESS
    }


}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android HttpClient : NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736530/android-httpclient-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: How are you chaining the two workers?
WorkManager's codelab has some sample on how to do it: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-workmanager/#5